# $twitter Branch.io Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, branch, ionic3, branch.io

ok when i add the twitter card to Branch.io iOS crashes and gives this error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key $twitter_player.'

```
     var properties = {
        $twitter_player:url,
        $twitter_player_width:600,
        $twitter_player_height:360,
        $twitter_card: 'player',
        canonicalIdentifier: type+'/'+id,
        canonicalUrl: 'shiafm://'+type+'/'+id,
        title: title,
        contentDescription: artist + " - "+ album,
        contentImageUrl: pic,
        //$deeplink_path: type+'/'+id,
        contentIndexingMode: 'public',
        contentMetadata: {
          type: type,
          id: id,
          title:title,
          pic:pic
        }
      }

      var analytics = {
        channel: 'facebook',
        feature: 'Sharing',
        campaign: 'Sharing',
        stage:  type,
        tags: [type,id,title,'ShiaFM']
      }
      var message = title;

      // create a branchUniversalObj variable to reference with other Branch methods
      var branchUniversalObj = null
      Branch.createBranchUniversalObject(properties).then(function (res) {
        branchUniversalObj = res

   //alert('Response: ' + JSON.stringify(res));

    branchUniversalObj.onShareSheetLaunched(function (res) {
      // android only
      //console.log(res)
    })
    branchUniversalObj.onShareSheetDismissed(function (res) {
      //console.log(res)
    })
    branchUniversalObj.onLinkShareResponse(function (res) {
      //console.log(res);
      var eventName = 'Shared'
      var metadata = { 'Title': title};
      Branch.userCompletedAction(eventName, metadata).then(function (res) {
      })
    })
    branchUniversalObj.onChannelSelected(function (res) {
      // android only
      //console.log(res)
    })
    branchUniversalObj.showShareSheet(analytics, properties, message);


  }).catch(function (err) {
    //alert('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err))
  })
```

Comment: make sure you do not have any special characters in the URL you are assigning to the parameter `$twitter_player`. The URL needs to be URI encoded if there are any special characters.

Comment: It is not about url encode

Comment: Can you provide all the data you are passing while creating the link?